# Temporarily rebind then safely re-attach library method

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, this, dynamic-rebinding

I'm building a module in the context of an existing library. Some of the library's functionality — specifically, `LIBRARY.module.add` (*for the sake of example: the actual functionality's much more elaborate*) —, which can be triggered in all sorts of scenarios, will destroy my module's UX, so I need to interrupt it to take account of my module's esoteric concerns.

I'm not allowed to re-write any part of the original library, and I'm not allowed to duplicate functionality which is supposedly covered by the library.

Existing code is something like this:

```
LIBRARY.moduleX = {
    two      : 2,
    addToTwo : function(addAnd){
        return this.two + addAnd;
    }
}
```

A key concern here is that `LIBRARY`'s modules are all written in literal object notation and their methods rely on `this`. Another concern is that the code base is continuously in flux. I can't rely on `addToTwo`'s arity or anything like that (in case someone extends it to take multiple operands or whatever).

So I've written this to execute as part of my component's initialization:

```
void function handleModuleX(){
    // Keep a reference before rebinding
    var LIBRARY_moduleX_addToTwo = LIBRARY.moduleX.addToTwo;

    // Restores the original binding
    function rebind(){
        LIBRARY.moduleX.addToTwo = function(){
            return LIBRARY_moduleX_addToTwo.apply(LIBRARY.moduleX, arguments);
        }
    }

    // Rebind to consider local logic
    LIBRARY.moduleX.addToTwo = function handleEsotericLogic(){
        if(unresolvedConcerns){
            stuff();
        }
        else {
            rebind();

            LIBRARY.moduleX.addToTwo();
        }
    }
}();
```

This appears to work. My concern is ultimately with the safety and legibility of the rebinding:

- Is this technique bulletproof, inasmuch as it doesn't make any assumptions about `addToTwo`?
- Is this as close as I can get to restoring the original binding?
- Can I achieve the same functionality without nesting so many scopes (obviously `rebind` can be written in to the `else` statement — it's only hoisted out for clarity)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit more research lead me to underscore's [`bind`](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-58) method, which does basically the same thing I did to polyfill [ECMAScript 5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)'s native Function method of the same name — which appears to be the only way I can avoid the 2 closures involved in the implementation above. So now my code is more verbose — because I just really didn't like the idea of calls on the library's method bouncing through my code on stack trace if possible (it's like I never touched it!):

```
function rebind(){
    if(Function.prototype.bind){
        LIBRARY.moduleX.addToTwo = LIBRARY_moduleX_addToTwo.bind(LIBRARY.moduleX);
    }
    else {
        LIBRARY.moduleX.addToTwo = function(){
            return LIBRARY_moduleX_addToTwo.apply(LIBRARY.moduleX, arguments);
        }
    }
}
```